# Multilayer canvas and click events (Createjs)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have an example using multilayer canvas.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="background">
        <div id="canvas">
            <canvas id="main" width="1024" height="768"></canvas>
            <canvas id="animation" width="1024" height="768"></canvas>            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#background {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 768px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(../Images/bg2.jpg) no-repeat;
    position: relative;   
}

#canvas {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
canvas{
    background: transparent;
    position:absolute;
}

#main {
    background: url(../Images/bg_ban.png) no-repeat;
}
```

In the main canvas some objects are drawn (these need to be *clickable*).

In animation canvas more objects are drawn. However this canvas (animation one) is above the main canvas, and it prevents being able to click on the objects in main canvas.

Can anybody help me understand why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible without manually injecting some functionality. Unfortunately the pointer-events CSS property is not yet well supported, so its not really an option. The best way would be to capture click events (etc) on the top stage, and propagate them manually (call the Stage mouse handlers on the lower stage).

I think its a decent idea to try and handle this internally in EaselJS, and have surfaced it to the team.

The other thing to consider is why you are using multiple Stages. Its not really necessary, unless you have a ton of static content in one stage, and don't want to redraw it each tick. In this case, you could cache it, and then it would be one draw call per tick, which should have a minimal effect.

Comment: Oh Lanny, i used to work with KineticJS framework, i found it have already supported multilayer canvas. Because of some reason, i want to learn CreateJS. I think in a mobile application, i don't want to update all objects when i call stage.update(). When i switch to CreateJS, i don't know why createJS doesn't have multilayer.

Comment: Its just not something that has been implemented. The benefits to have multiple canvases are reduced thanks to the prevalence of GPU-accelerated browsers, so its less of an issue than it might have been a few years ago. We can definitely look into adding some kind of support.

Answer (score 2):

You'll try a property of css [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

```
#animation {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: I want to handle all events fire up on all objects in 2 layers? How do I?

Comment: How about to create parent div for canvas elements and add listeners to it?